# why if $h_{k}=f^{'}_{n_p}$ then $2\leq k\leq p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I read article ***An elementary proof of Komlós-Révész theorem in Hilbert spaces*** by  Guessous Mohamed (see page 328). But I don't understand why : if $h_{m+j}=f^{'}_{n_p}$ then $2\leq k\leq p$
[image]